# How to store data in a 2D vector within class private?

Tags: c++, class, vector, struct

Basically I'm getting data from a txt file and putting it into a vector in one class function, then in another class function i'm retrieving that data - but i'm getting an error message when I try to build.

In the private area of my class called 'Level' I defined a struct:

```
struct largeTile
{
    int texture;
}
```

Next in the private area of my class called 'Level' I defined a 2D vector to hold the struct objects:

```
vector<vector<largeTile> > vvint(int BIG_TILE_ROWS, vector<largeTile>(int BIG_TILE_COLUMNS));
```

Within the class that is called 'Level' I have a function that will fill the vector array with struct objects from a txt file:

```
for(int r = 0; r < vvint.size(); r++)
{
    for(int c = 0; c < vvint.at(0).size(); c++)
    {
        fileData >> vvint[r][c].texture;
    }
}
```

Though I get this build message, what am I doing wrong? I already defined the class type as 'largeTile' no?

error: '((Level*)this)->Level::vvint' does not have a class type

Comment: Can you post a [complete example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've declared `vvint` to be a function. I guess you meant

```
vector<vector<largeTile>> vvint = 
    vector<vector<largeTile>>(BIG_TILE_ROWS, vector<largeTile>(BIG_TILE_COLUMNS));
```

to initialise it with `ROWS` vectors each of size `COLUMNS`.

Comment: The error went away and it builds, though in my two for loops it doesn't add the file data. hmm..

Comment: @doomglhfcn: Then you'd better step through in your debugger to see what's going wrong. Or post [enough code to demonstrate the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) if you need help.